# Already defined variables into multi-dimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

Sorry guys, I'm pretty new to this whole coding thing. I just can't seem to wrap my head around multi-dimensional arrays. I'm getting all my info from a CSV file that is being processed with PHP. I have two already defined variables from the CSV. Schools and Rooms. Each row on the CSV determines what school and what room go together. 
The data from the CSV will look like this.

> School Gender  HomeRoom
>   10             F              1
>   10             F              2
>   1028         F              1
>   10             F              2
>   10             F              4
>   1028         F              8
>   1026         F              5
>   1028         F              1
>   1026         F              1

Example:

```
$school = array('10', '1028','1026')

$room = array('1','2','4','5','8').
```

Preferred outcome:

```
$list = array('10' => array('1','2','4'), '1028' => array('1','8'), '1026' => array('1','5'))
```

The schools will have multiple rooms
I basically want to create a new array of rooms indexed by schools. I've tried a whole slew of things but this always gets me. Any tips, pointers, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Also let me know if I need to add more information.

Comment: Please explain the exact requirement.

Comment: `$school['school1'] = array('room1', 'room2');` etc...

Comment: Can you give sample data rather than 'an array with a bunch of schools'

Comment: $schoolWithRooms = array(
    'school1' => array(
    'room1', 'room2'
    ),
   'school2' => array('roomX', 'roomY')
);

Comment: **How are we supposed to know which rooms exist within a specific school**? Or have they all got all 7 rooms

Comment: Show us (in your question) an example of the 2 arrays with some ACTUAL representative data in them, and then show us the result you want in the new array

Comment: I've updated the post. Sorry I'm so vague, completely new to this.

Comment: Maybe you also need to show us an example of the CSV file as well. I still dont understand how to allocate the correct rooms to the correct school

Comment: Please try to post code that is valid, without syntax errors. Take some care in the things you do.

Comment: I've updated post again with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$csv =<<<CSV
School Gender HomeRoom
10 F 1
10 F 2
1028 F 1
10 F 2
10 F 4
1028 F 8
1026 F 5
1028 F 1
1026 F 1
CSV;
foreach(explode("\n", $csv) as $line) {
    $items[] = str_getcsv($line, ' ');
}

$headings = array_shift($items);
foreach($items as $item)
    $list[$item[0]][] = $item[2];

$list = array_map('array_unique', $list);

var_export($list);
```

Output:

```
array (
    10 => 
    array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    3 => '4',
    ),
    1028 => 
    array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '8',
    ),
    1026 => 
    array (
    0 => '5',
    1 => '1',
    ),
)
```